# How to change the ng-model value to upper case for validation

Tags: angularjs

```
 <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'active': field == 'country', 'has-error has-feedback' :Country.$invalid && submitted}">
        <label class="col-xs-2 control-label muted" for="Country">Country</label>
        <div class="col-xs-9">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Country" name="Country" ng-change="ChangesMade()" ng-model="data.country" ng-readonly="previewMode" ng-focus="field='country';showHelp()" ng-required="contactPersonId">   
        </div>
    </div>
```

Based on this field the state s required. But it can be either capital or lower case how i can i add filter to it

```
<div class="col-xs-4 pad-none" ng-class="{'has-error has-feedback' : (data.country =='US' || data.country =='CANADA' | uppercase) && State.$invalid && submitted }">
    <div class="col-xs-4" >
        <label class="control-label muted" for="State">State</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-8 pad-none">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="State" name="State" ng-change="ChangesMade()" ng-model="data.state" ng-readonly="previewMode" ng-focus="field='state';showHelp()" ng-required="data.country  =='US'  || data.country  =='Canada' ">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
ng-required="data.country.toUpperCase() === 'US' || data.country  =='Canada'"
```

Comment: Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2EjJ3/1/). Typing 'US' in the first text field, in any case permutation, makes the other required(denoted by the red background).